# Start Wildfly at background with Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, wildfly, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I would start the WildFly (JBOSS) standalone server automatically in background with Vagrant. Unfortunately I cant do that, only foreground.(Ubuntu 16.04)
I've tried the following.

Ubuntu 16.04
Wildfly 9.0.2

1. I put the following lines into the Vagrantfile but not helped.

   ```
     config.vm.provision "shell",

     inline: "/home/vagrant/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/standalone.sh &"
   ```
2. I tried to run the following command from script what I put to the vm

   ```
     /home/vagrant/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/standalone_UTC.sh &
   ```
3. I tried to checnge the JBOSS env variable

   ```
    LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
   ```

The Wildfly not start without any error. If I start the wildfly without & its working.

Comment: what is the error wildfly gives you?

Comment: Nothing. The wildfly not started. seems the rows are ignored.
In case of LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 seems the variable ignored as well